# How to get exact single match in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Documents in ES look like this

```
              {
                    "indicator": "27.213.61.96",
                    "itype": "ipv4",
                   
                }
    
    
    
              { 
                    "indicator": "http://27.213.61.96:44375/Mozi.m",
                    "itype": "url",
             
                }
```

wanted to get "indicator": "27.213.61.96" object and for that tries with match_phrase, term query and constant_score query which is as below

```
{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : { 
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { 
                    "indicator" : "27.213.61.96"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "indicator": "27.213.61.96"
        }
    }
}
```

**In response getting both the objects** but want only below object in response. Is there any way to get that. **Mapping is the default mapping and any way to get excepted result without changing mapping.**

```
{
                    "indicator": "27.213.61.96",
                    "itype": "ipv4",
                   
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `.keyword` to the `indicator` field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the `".keyword"` after `indicator` field). Try out this below query -

```
    {
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "indicator.keyword": "27.213.61.96"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64922836",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "indicator": "27.213.61.96",
          "itype": "ipv4"
        }
      }
    ]
```